# cannot find function `memory_teardown` in module `sandbox`

Tags: polkadot, frontier, evm

I am trying to add **evm_pallet** with NPOS consensus( i.e babe and staking) but while adding **evm_pallet** to runtime getting error.[image].

### active toolchain

1.59-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)

rustc 1.59.0 (9d1b2106e 2022-02-23)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using some older Substrate version?

Nevertheless, it looks like you didn't enabled the `std` feature for `evm_pallet` when building for native. This should solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried to build using rust 1.63 but it still shows the error and i have added Evm_pallet std feature in  cargo.toml

Comment: Rust version is not related to this. Do you have a link to your runtime?